# Ruby on Rails - Routing Error (uninitialized constant UsersController)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-follow

I am building a Follow system for my first app, based on Michael Hartl's chapter 11 tutorial (http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#top). On user pages, it displays # of followers and # of following. But when I hover over the link to followers or following on user profiles, it is directed to link to localhost:3000/users/1/followers or localhost:3000/users/1/following. This is correct. But  I click either link, I get the following error listed below. Thanks for helping!

> Routing Error
>   uninitialized constant UsersController

routes.rb

```
get "user/show"

devise_for :users
match 'users/:id' => 'user#show', as: :user

resources :users do
  member do
    get :following, :followers
  end
end
```

user_controller.rb

```
def following
  @title = "Following"
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @users = @user.followed_users.paginate(page: params[:page])
  render 'show_follow'
end

def followers
  @title = "Followers"
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @users = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page])
  render 'show_follow'
end
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your file name from `user_controller.rb` to `users_controller.rb`

If you're getting the error `ActionView::MissingTemplate in Users#following Missing partial users/user` then that's exactly where you should look, `views/users/_user.html.erb` - do you have this file? Have you named it correctly?

Comment: excellent, thanks! just one more follow up. in my 'show_follow' file that I render, I render @users, and I get a new error: ActionView::MissingTemplate in Users#following
Missing partial users/user with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee]}

Comment: I am only able to post limited code here for now. But the line item is:
        <%= render @users %>

Comment: See here for the code I used: http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/following-users#code-show_follow_view